# Deploy coffeescripted derbyjs app to heroku

Tags: heroku, derbyjs

When deploying to heroku I get the following error log:

```
2013-08-05T18:14:39.217252+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2013-08-05T18:14:43.819448+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `node server.js`
2013-08-05T18:14:45.272628+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2013-08-05T18:14:45.274663+00:00 app[web.1]: module.js:340
2013-08-05T18:14:45.277076+00:00 app[web.1]:     throw err;
2013-08-05T18:14:45.277256+00:00 app[web.1]:           ^
2013-08-05T18:14:45.279157+00:00 app[web.1]: Error: Cannot find module '/app/server.js'
2013-08-05T18:14:45.279157+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:338:15)
2013-08-05T18:14:45.279157+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Function.Module._load (module.js:280:25)
2013-08-05T18:14:45.279157+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:497:10)
2013-08-05T18:14:45.279157+00:00 app[web.1]:     at startup (node.js:119:16)
2013-08-05T18:14:45.279157+00:00 app[web.1]:     at node.js:901:3
2013-08-05T18:14:46.719239+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 8
2013-08-05T18:14:46.736590+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
```

I'm new to derbyjs as well as heroku ... great, great, great tools, anyway!

So, why is the app complaining about a /app/server.js file?
It's a coffeescript project, and as far as I am aware, it uses browserify to deliver js on the fly. Also, there simply is no server.coffee in the app dir ... as it is the app dir, how can there ever be a server.js in it?? well, surely some meaning hidden from me for now.

Guys, can you help out?

**I'm using:**
Derby 0.5.9
Heroku Toolbelt ... just installed before writing this task
Deploy steps as explained on derbyjs.com

Cheers, Joehannes

Comment: I found I just need to compile all the coffeescript files - anyway, that seems brute to me. I just would love a derby-way-tutorial on how it is intended to be built/bundled ... I see coffeify comes as a dependency, I guess that's it